# Arbitrary constants in solutions of differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

While introducing myself to differential equations, I read that the solution to a differential equation may contain an arbitrary constant without being a general solution.

I have been solving initial value problems under the concept of anti-differentiation for a long time now. I am a little aware of general and particular solutions from my engineering classes. I have always thought that a solution having an arbitrary constant cannot be anything other than a general solution. I don't think a particular solution can have an arbitrary constant in it. The lines that I read today left me curious. I am really curious to see these equations and maybe know how they work.

Comment: If you face a differential equation of order $n$, the general solution contains $n$ constants. Now, if you are given $m$ conditions $(m \leq n)$, $m$ of these constants "disappear" since fixed by  the conditions.

Comment: So, the solution, having some constants, is now a particular solution under a few conditions( m ), right?

Comment: I think what your text is trying to say is that a solution containing the right number of arbitrary constants, although it is a "general" solution (not a particular solution), yet it may fail to be the *most* general solution; i.e., there may be particular solutions which can not be obtained by assigning values to the arbitrary constants.

Comment: For example, the (non-linear) first order equation $$\frac{dy}{dt}=y^2$$ has the "general solution" $$y=\frac1{C-t}$$ but it also has the "singular solution" $$y=0$$ which is not covered by the "general solution".

Comment: This is a very interesting example. I appreciate it. It does justify your "most general solution" statement. But there still is a room for doubt about whether the text is exactly conveying what you just did.

Comment: On my opinion, the example is dictutable. One can consider that $C=\infty$ belongs to the set of values of $C$. So, the trivial solution  $y=0$ in included into the general solution $y=\frac{1}{C-t}$

Comment: Note that the solution can be written as : $y=\frac{c}{1-c\:t}$. The particular solution with $c=0$ is $y(x)=0$.

Comment: @JJacquelin, the solution you provided above, $y\rightarrow 0$ only when $t\rightarrow \infty$. As far as I know, infinity can never belong to a set of real values because it is not a number, but "$\infty$" tells us about the behavior of functions under certain conditions, don't you think?

Comment: OK. But the solution $y=\frac{c}{1-ct}$ isn't for $t\to\infty$. It is for $c=0$ which gives $y(t)=0$, any finite $t$.

Comment: @JJacquelin, while yours and bof's solutions perfectly satisfy the differential equation, the two aren't the same solutions because the functions are not equal. This tells me that there are two solutions to one differential equation. I am wondering if this result can have some consequences in physics and engineering.

Comment: $y=\frac{c}{1-ct}$ and $y=\frac{1}{C-t}$ are the same function. Only the symbol of the constants differs : $c=\frac{1}{C}$ since they are any constants, in fact it is the same, but written on different manner. It very common that a function can be expressed on various forms, with different symbols of the variables and parameters. This do not create a lot of different functions !

Comment: Oh my goodness! I did not realize that your solution was with a $c$ and not bof's $C$. My bad. But here is a doubt. You took $C=\frac{1}{c}$. Here, you cannot take $c=0$ because that would make $C$ undefined. $C$ being undefined makes $y$ meaningless, I think. I really should have clarified this earlier.

Comment: We can only take $c\rightarrow 0$( $C\rightarrow \infty$ ) for $y\rightarrow 0$. $C$ tending to infinity is not desirable, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can find examples (not exclusively) when the solution includes multi-valuated functions, which is the sometimes the case of inverse functions. For example, the ODE :
$$\cos(y(x))\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$
has this family of solutions : 
$$y(x)=\sin^{-1}(x+c_1)$$
This solution includes an arbitrary constant $c_1$ but is not the general solution which is :
$$y(x)=\sin^{-1}(x+c_1)+2\pi\:n$$

Comment: This is a great example!

Comment: Lastly, the text mentioned that establishing that a solution "is" general requires deeper knowledge of the theory of differential equations. Although I am a beginner at differential equations, could I, if you could provide, take a peak at the procedure?

Comment: I am afraid that it is not possible to answer on a general manner. There is no general method to solve all kind of differential equations and so, for the generality of the solutions found in all cases. But they are some particular methods that you will progressively learn.